# Automorphism group of $G\times G$ has an element of order 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Given that $G$ is a non-trivial group, prove that Aut$(G\times G)$ has an element of order 2.

At this time I lack good intuition for automorphism groups, so I would appreciate some hints about how the statement above be proved.

Comment: Can you think of an isomorphism $G\times G\to G\times G$ that is not the identity? What is its order? (There aren't too many choices, since you don't know anything about $G$.)

Comment: If we don't know anything about $G$, how can we know anything about the order of such an isomorphism?

Comment: Have you figured out what the isomorphism is? If you do, it should be clear to you why you can know what its order is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$(g,h)\mapsto (h,g)$$
$$\textbf{}$$

Comment: Best answer ever.

Comment: The OP asked for a hint...

Comment: @lhf I think this is a reasonable hint!

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* Given two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$, find an isomorphism $G_1 \times G_2 \to G_2 \times G_1$.